# $H, K, HK$ is a subgroup of G, then $|G:H\cap K|$ divides $|G:H||G:K|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across this fact that says if $H, K, HK$ is a subgroup of G, then $|G:H\cap K|$ divides $|G:H||G:K|$. I can prove that $|G:H\cap K| \leq |G:H||G:K|$. However, I can't get the divisor relationship. Can someone explain to me why this is true. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$|G:H\cap K|=\frac{|G|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{|G|}{|H|}\cdot \frac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}$

Now, note that $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ and $|HK|$ divides $|G|$ **(Since, subgroup)**

Thus, $\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}.n=|G|$. Clearly, $\frac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}$ divides $|G:K|=|G|/|K|$